# Session is bleeding over to another customer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am storing a name and address in session in a static session class. When a customer pulls up the payment screen, I prefill the form with the name and address. If customer A pulls up the credit card screen and then customer B pulls up the same screen, customer B has the name and address of customer A.

I'm thinking this is happening due to a 'static' session class? If this is the case, how do I avoid this?

Here is my MySession class:

```
  public static class MySession
  {
    public static string BranchNumber { set; get; }
    public static string AccountNumber { set; get; }
    public static string Name { set; get; }
    public static string CustomerEmail { get; set; }
    public static string Street { get; set; }
    public static string Zip { get; set; }
    public static string Zip4 { get; set; }
}
```

And my form:

```
@model  SssMobileIInquiry.Models.HomeModels.CreditCard

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Credit Card Payment";
}

<div class="container">

  @using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitCreditCardCharge", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {

    <h4>Credit Card Payment</h4>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Name
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 focus">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NameOnCard, new { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Street
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Street, new { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Zip Code
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZipCode, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "9" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Card Number
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CardNumber, new { @class = "form-control" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Expiration Date
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 datefieldsmall">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDateMonth, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "2", @placeholder = "MM" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9 datefieldsmall">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExpirationDateYear, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "2", @placeholder = "YY" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        CVV Number
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PinNumber, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "4" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        Amount
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PaymentAmount, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "7" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="warning">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PaymentAmount)
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input id="submitpayment" class="btn btn-primary btn-block buttonx accountinfobutton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  }


  @using (Html.BeginForm("AccountInfo", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
  {
    <div class="row">
      <input id="submitpayment" class="btn btn-primary btn-block buttonx accountinfobutton" type="submit" value="Account" />
    </div>
  }

</div>
```

And my ActionResults:

```
public ActionResult CreditCard()
{
  if (MySession.CorporationId == Guid.Empty || string.IsNullOrEmpty(MySession.AccountNumber))
  {
    return View("Index");
  }

  var model = new Models.HomeModels.CreditCard();
  model.NameOnCard = MySession.Name;
  model.Street = MySession.Street;
  model.ZipCode = MySession.Zip;

  model.PaymentAmount = MySession.TotalBalance.Contains("-") ? "" : MySession.TotalBalance;


  if (MySession.BudgetBalance.GetNumericValue() > 0 && MySession.BudgetRate.GetNumericValue() > 0)
  {
    model.PaymentAmount = MySession.BudgetBalance;
  }

  return View("CreditCard", model);
}
```

I am populating my model with MySession:

```
  model.NameOnCard = MySession.Name;
  model.Street = MySession.Street;
  model.ZipCode = MySession.Zip;
```

I'm not sure why the customer information is being displayed for another account logged in. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using static. Static means there is only 1 copy of the class and is shared throughout the application. You need to change it so it isn't static and you must instantiate this for each user.

Comment: ty for the info. I suspected as much. How would I access the class through the webpage if it is instantiated on the code behind?

Comment: Same as you are now. You just need to store it into a Session variable, or other persistent store. If the session variable is empty, the class can be instantiated and save to session so it's always available. If there is a database backing the data, the initial population can be pulled out of the database. A key is to always ensure that you check for an empty session variable and take appropriate actions to make sure the class is created. Session is tricky and can go away for any number of reasons.